# Unable to start the Atom Editor without internet connection

Tags: windows-10, atom-editor

I have installed the *Atom Editor* on Windows 10,
but when I try to run it with no internet connection, it won't launch.

These are my specs:

- Atom    : 1.34.0
- Electron: 2.0.16
- Chrome  : 61.0.3163.100
- Node    : 8

I've searched the *Atom* discussion, but found nothing in there.
Does anyone have any clue?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Have you checked the Event Viewer or Atom logs for further information? Does the executable actually attempt to run at all?

Comment: @music2myear nothing is happinng and no new logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enabling the loopback adapter solves this issue

and that is how to enable it

1. access your device manager,
2. Click on any category e.g. "Network Adapter"
3. then click on "action" at the top of the window
   and select "Add legacy hardware"
4. Click "next" on the window that pops up
   Select the 2nd option on the next screen "install manually"
5. Then select "Network adapter" and click next. Wait for next window to load
   Choose manufacturer as "Microsoft"
6. Find the "loopback" adapter and click next and next again.
   Done

Comment: Interesting. How loopback adapter is connected to Atom Editor? I'm using it without any issue.

Comment: @Biswapriyo it's a problem with the last relese of atom..  the main issue is with the elctron version that crashes silently when there is no internet connection